# Get Java Compiler Warning for Unconsumed Return Value

Tags: java, return-value

I’m making a change to a commonly used function to add a return a value where it was originally a void function.

From:

```
        public void foo()
        { 
           // do something 
        }
```

To:

```
        public int foo()
        {
            // do something
            return 0;
        }
```

Is it possible to have the compiler issue a warning when `foo()` is invoked and the return value is not consumed?

I get an unused warning if the return is consumed and not used, but I want a warning to ensure it’s at least consumed.

Want a warning that the return from foo() is not consumed: `foo();`

OK: `int x = foo();`

Comment: Such a thing is possible with Error Prone's [`@CheckReturnValue` annotation](http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/CheckReturnValue). (Other solutions may be available)

Comment: Error Prone seems a bit like Lint.